# Thrift Server is crashing due to "RetriesExhaustedException"

Tags: hadoop, hbase, thrift, hortonworks-data-platform

When running thrift (/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift) it stops working every once in a while.
In the logs I can see the exception:

```
2015-11-12 11:56:11,926 WARN [thrift-worker-3] thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler: Can't get the location 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:309)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:153) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:811) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.scannerOpenWithScan(ThriftServerRunner.java:1451) 
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source) 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.invoke(HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.java:67) 
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.scannerOpenWithScan(Unknown Source) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$scannerOpenWithScan.getResult(Hbase.java:4609) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$scannerOpenWithScan.getResult(Hbase.java:4593) 
 at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39) 
 at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer$ClientConnnection.run(TBoundedThreadPoolServer.java:289) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: hconnection-0x20ae27f0 closed 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1146) 
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300)
 ... 22 more
```

I end up restarting thrift to get it working again.
I've tried implementing the following workaround found [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/hbase-thrift-Failed-to-get-region-location/td-p/32724) but its still crashing:

```
<property>
<name>hbase.thrift.connection.max-idletime</name>
<value>1800000</value>
</property>
```

We are using HDP 2.3.0 stack from HortonWorks /  HBase 1.1.1.2.3.0.0-2557

Comment: I also have this issue. Tried the workaround unsuccessfully. Still randomly the connection closes and I get "Can't get the location" error or get timeouts, then a "RetriesExhaustedException". I originally thought it was only crashing after I passed an invalid command/parameter, but now it will crash if I'm only using valid commands. I.E., the same command will work one minute, but the next minute I'll start getting timeouts. (using Hadoop Version 2.5.1, and using Thrift API from c#)

Answer (score 2):

This is an ongoing issue with HBase. There are two seperate tickets regarding this problem: [HBASE-14533](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14533) and [HBASE-14196](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14196). Both tickets provide a patch to resolve the problem.

Regarding to [Pankaj Kumar's comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14533?focusedCommentId=15106617&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15106617) from 01/19 the issue can be resolved if you merge both patches. Maybe this helps in your case, too.

Comment: I'm attempting this now, but I can't execute the patch, and I can't find anywhere online where it tells how to install it.

Comment: Its a patch for the SourceCode. Download the Source Code of your hbase version.

Apply patches with git am < foobar.parch

Compile the Sourcecode.